# Лицензирование при командной разработке

Tags: лицензирование

**Контекст**: Веду разработку проекта 9й месяц, кода много, код хороший, конца и края этому не видно. В OpenSource пока не хочу. Подумываю о командной разработке без риска потерять права на свой и совместный труд. Очевидно что мне:

- Нужно написать "правую" лицензию к продукту, чтобы защитить свои права на продукт
- Делая пул-реквест коллега как-то должен передать мне права на использование написанного им кода мной в любых целях и на любой срок. Чтобы не получилось так, что он в суде отстаивает свои авторские права, а я:

  - или покупай лицензию на его код
  - или удаляй его труды и переписывай сам заново

**Вопрос**: Как юридически защитить проект, чтобы у меня было достаточно прав на наш совместный труд и никто не мог этот труд частично или полностью погубить? Как моим коллегам передавать мне права на их труды, и как мне это все хранить, контролировать? Как это обычно делается, может быть есть какие-то best practices

Может быть можно мой исходный код лицензировать как BSD License например, и принимать только те пул-реквесты, которые лицензируются автором согласно BSD License, а перед этим на это все наложить ограничение в виде Соглашения о конфиденциальности. Чем плох такой метод?

Comment: Уточните, коллега платно работает и устроен к вам в качестве сотрудника? Есть ли у коллеги параллельное место работы или собственные проекты?

Comment: Проект не запущен, денег не приносит, юр. лицо не оформлено. Пока никто никакого когда мне не шлет, хочу подстелить, чтоб не больно падать было. Так что первое время работа бесплатная, на энтузиазме, совмещенная с другим местом работы. А в перспективе, конечно устрою в качестве сотрудника

Comment: И чем это грозит? А если оформлен (но какое-то время платить все равно нечем)?

Comment: Ну это то ладно, он сможет потребовать удаления своего кода из репозитория? Или слить репозиторий в сеть на законных основаниях?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он больше относится к юридической сфере, чем к программированию.

Comment: @svmitin, с подобными вопросами лучше к юристам обращаться,

Comment: @Streletz Будет лучше если ответ на этот вопрос будет на StackOverflow, чем на сайте юридической направленности, так как он имеет прямое отношение к программированию. Если найду ответ ближайшие дни, отвечу на вопрос сам

Comment: @svmitin, вопрос больше относится к защите авторских прав, а к программированию (по определению) относится весьма посредственно. Да и не думаю, что где-то в открытом доступе вам на него ответят. Здесь много подводных камней и много завязано, простите, на деньги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Не имея юр. лица

Можно заключить договор *авторского заказа* с привлекаемым программистом, включив в него:

- условия о передаче Вам *исключительных прав* на разработанный им код;
- условия о возможности использования Ваших разработок
- назначать существенные санкции на случай, если произойдет какая-то утечка
- условия о конфиденциальности

Авторское право (ст. 1255 ГК РФ) при этом изменено быть не может в силу того, что оно неотъемлемо от того, кто создал этот код, а вот исключительные права на него могут быть переданы по договору Вам.

> **ГК РФ Статья 1296. Произведения, созданные по заказу**
>
> 1. **Исключительное право на программу для ЭВМ, базу данных или иное произведение, созданные по договору, предметом которого было создание такого произведения (по заказу), принадлежит заказчику**, если договором между подрядчиком (исполнителем) и заказчиком не предусмотрено иное.
> 2. В случае, если исключительное право на произведение в соответствии с пунктом 1 настоящей статьи принадлежит заказчику, подрядчик (исполнитель) вправе, поскольку договором не предусмотрено иное, использовать такое произведение для собственных нужд на условиях безвозмездной простой (неисключительной) лицензии в течение всего срока действия исключительного права.

## Имея юр. лицо

Здесь появляются дополнительные возможности

- Можно оформлять результаты чужого труда как *служебное произведение*

> **Статья 1295 ГК РФ Служебное произведение**
>
> 2. **Исключительное право на служебное произведение принадлежит работодателю**, если трудовым или гражданско-правовым договором между работодателем и автором не предусмотрено иное

- Можно пройти *государственную регистрацию программ для ЭВМ и баз данных*, зарегистрировав ПО *на себя*

> **Статья 1262 ГК РФ Государственная регистрация программ для ЭВМ и баз данных**
>
> 1. Правообладатель в течение срока действия исключительного права на программу для ЭВМ или на базу данных может по своему желанию зарегистрировать такую программу или такую базу данных в федеральном органе исполнительной власти по интеллектуальной собственности.

**PS.**: Задал этот вопрос юристам на сайте Pravoved.ru. Их ответы [здесь](https://pravoved.ru/question/2737659/#a3849460)